# ExpandDL not working on private Dynamic Group

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm working with an Outlook Web Add-in with Office.js that uses EWS to handle part of our mail merge sending process. We send mail merge emails that use Distribution Lists and Dynamic Distribution Groups. Our issue is that when we do the ExpandDL call with a Dynamic Distribution Group that is hidden from the user doing the call, we get the following response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="2220" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2018_01_08"/>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <m:ExpandDLResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:ExpandDLResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
            <m:MessageText>No results were found.</m:MessageText>
            <m:ResponseCode>ErrorNameResolutionNoResults</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
        </m:ExpandDLResponseMessage>
    </m:ResponseMessages>
</m:ExpandDLResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is the sample request soap that we're using to call ExpandDL, where 
`example-DDG@example.com` is a Dynamic Distribution Group that is hidden/private and the user requesting this call does not have permission to view it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2013" soap:mustUnderstand="0"/>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <m:ExpandDL>
        <m:Mailbox>
            <t:EmailAddress>example-DDG@example.com</t:EmailAddress>
        </m:Mailbox>
    </m:ExpandDL>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What is the intended implementation here? Are we suppose to get a more appropriate error message on not having the right permissions to expand or is the user suppose to have the ability expand the Dynamic Distribution Group?

We would like to know how to handle this case so that we can print the appropriate error or keep the Dynamic Distribution Group unexpanded and send the mail merge as it is.

Answer (score 1):

> Our issue is that when we do the ExpandDL call with a Dynamic Distribution Group that is hidden from the user doing the call

If its hidden then as per the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/expanddl-operation

> The group should not be hidden from the address list and each member should have a non-empty e-mail address.